# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input on line 1

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object

```
function Driver(draw, name) {
    this.draw = draw;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Chrome says the Unexpected end of input is on line 1. I don't see how this is possible, since I need lines 2 and 3 to set up the function. I closed both my {} and my ().

Comment: some other part of your code is causing it, you will have to show more of your code

Comment: probably from another part of code, I would try to insert {} and () to see where they match up

Comment: Thanks, I've been able to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: @DavidDubczak Mind to share it with us?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I moved things around and it worked.